# Qt (Creator) with WinSocks (ws2_32)

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, winsock

I want to use an older code-fragment in my Qt-project, which is using WinSocks.
I created my program with Qt Creator and I don't know, how I can link to the ws2_32-Library.  I already added `LIBS += -lws2_32` to my .pro, but nothing happened. So how can I link to this library?

**edit:** Where can I find the ws2_32.lib to include it? Do I have to download it first? I know it comes with "Visual Studio", but I don't use it and I don't want to use it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

ok, when you know it, it's really simple.The Qt-SDK comes with a WinSock2-Library, called `libws2_32.a`.The only thing you have to
do, is to enter this line in your .pro:

> `LIBS += C:\Qt\2009.04\mingw\lib\libws2_32.a`

this includes the winsock2-library to your project and you have nothing else to do.

You may do this slightly more simply by using this line in your .pro:

```
LIBS += -lws2_32
```

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to use the full or relative path (depends on what library paths you have in your enviroment) to the `.lib`s.

From the qmake manual:

```
win32:LIBS += c:/mylibs/math.lib
```

Comment: ok, I think this could work. But look at my edit, where can I find this ws2_32.lib?

Comment: QtCreator is based on mingw, so `win32:LIBS += ws2_32.lib` should work i think. Can't check at the moment though as i'm on a mac here.

Answer (score 0):

You need too to add the path to the headers in order to add the function's signatures of a dynamic library.

Use the [`INCLUDEPATH`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath) variable into the .pro file.

Answer (score 0):

I have `ws2_32.lib` in `c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDK\Lib\WS2_32.Lib` it comes with the [platform sdk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK).  I have a very old version from Feb 2003 I think, I only needed it when I was using VC6.0, but I assume it is in the latest version too.