# Linking winsock library with `LIBS += -lws2_32` in Qt doesn't work?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, winsock2

I've also tried linking with the path on my computer which is

`C:\Qt\Tools\mingw48_32\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libws2_32.a`

but to no avail.

Is there any other way to link the winsock library?

Source code:

.pro file: http://privatepaste.com/2ac921e4f5

main.cpp: http://privatepaste.com/557fe9c297

These are the only two files that aren't at their original settings.

Comment: show us the compiler output

Comment: http://puu.sh/7KzWj.png the error I get after using pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib") I get these errors as well http://puu.sh/7KA1f.png

Comment: Again remove #pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib") comment if you are compiling with gcc or mingw.

Comment: Please include relevant information in your question. Linking to external pastebins leads to link rot.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737629%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Instead of pragma you could just add it using Project Properties (in Solution Explorer right click the project name and select properties)->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input and add ws2_32.lib to Additional Dependencies. In VS2010 this is a semicolon seperated list, so at the end, just before %(AdditionalDependencies), add ws2_32.lib; to the list.

THIS IS YOUR CODE

```
s1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); 
a.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); 
a.sin_family = AF_INET; 
a.sin_port = htons(1000);
```

**a** doesn't have those methods, the socket does, replace `a` with `s1` please

The same goes for this:

```
lLength = connect(s1, (SOCKADDR*)&a, sizeof(a));
```

just a question

#### Why are you passing the main window

```
MainWindow w; 
w.show(); 
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &w);
```

#### to your WSAStartup??

Pass a `WSADATA wsaData;`

Comment: This error is happening in Qt not VS. Perhaps I should have specified that in the title.

Comment: [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742273/qt-creator-with-winsocks-ws2-32)

Comment: I've already tried everything in that thread.

Comment: we'll need a minimal working example of your problem, specifically the include files

Comment: Ok I'll add the source code of my program in its entirety in my main post.

Comment: **minimal working example**

Comment: Try adding LIBS += -lws2_32 to your .pro file and pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib") to your main.cpp file. Afterwards add this: http://privatepaste.com/f39fd056a2 code to your main.cpp file and see if it compiles.

Comment: Gives me the same error, it's because winsock library isn't linked.

Comment: did you removed the pragma as well? and removed the extra `LIBS += -lws2_32` on you pro file?

Comment: Oh I know why it didn't work, because I named my variables the same as the default Qt variables.

Comment: There are no errors now except for: http://puu.sh/7KEVk.png And my program doesn't connect to the server I want it to because the program doesn't have the winsock library.

Comment: I know, try to be more verbose with your variables, but not too verbose. But for example MainWindow w... w doesn't tell you anything, so after 10000 lines of code where you see w you'll start asking yourself what was w in the first place. I recommend reading `Code Complete` by Steve McConell

Comment: We keep telling you to remove pragma man, I think this is the fourth time

Comment: I'll try removing the pragma, very doubtful though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357163/pragma-pack-wont-compile

Comment: pragma belongs to visual c++, you said you are using qt, you gotta know your environment mister doubtful

Comment: And it worked, thanks a bunch. pragma has always seemed like an obligatory thing to me. I guess it is, but only in visual studio. First time using Qt.

Comment: even when using visual studio pragma sucks... stick to project properties

Comment: I think the problem has nothing to do with Winsock or Qt and everything to do with your lack of knowledge of how the c++ compiling and linking process occurs. I suggest finding some beginner tutorials that explain what happens and why you can't use VS static libraries when compiling with MinGW, and vice versa.

Comment: You're right, it was entirely because of my incompetence.

Comment: Ignorance is not the same as incompetence, ignorance can be fixed with education.